# Angular Scroll to specific item in the list created using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, kendo-ui

In my AngularJS app I have two lists created using `ng-repeat`.

List one lists all the food categories like:

```
Meat, Fruits, Vegetables, Poultry, Dry Fruits ... etc.
```

List two lists all the foods like:

```
Eggs, Chicken, Oranges, Apple, Banana ... etc.
```

List number two lists food items in groups like, all the Meat items first and then all Fruits.

I have created both of these lists using `div` and `ng-repeat`, in one page.
Each element in the both of the lists has unique ID.

**What I want to achieve:**

When user select one of the food category from `list one`, then `list two` should scroll to that particular category related food items.

For example if user selects `Fruits` in `list one` then, `list two` should scroll to `Oranges` item.

**UPDATE**

Also is it possible to select item in list one when user scrolls to specific group? For example if user scrolls to `Chicken` in list two then in list one `Meat` should be selected.

Answer (score 3):

I personnally would use Angular's [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

```
    this.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $anchorScroll(id);
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5480/)

Comment: I am using angular kendo so I can not use `$anchorScroll` as per the kendo documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this for a list1 item:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemType in itemTypes">
  <li ng-click="$scope.scrollThere({{"."+itemType}})">{{itemType}}</li>
</div>
```

With something like this for list2:

```
<div id="list2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 30px;" ng-repeat="item2 in theItems">
  <li class="{{item2.itemType}}">{{item2.itemName}}</li>
</div>
```

And then keep track of which element to scroll to somehow like this just goes to the next item in the fruits when fruit is clicked?:

```
$scope.scrollThere = scrollThere;
$scope.count = { fruit: 0 };
function scrollThere(foodType){
    angular.element('#list2').animate({
      scrollTop: angular.element(foodType)[count[foodType]++].offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

And making sure the y overflow is set to scroll in the css.

Or instead of keeping count with an object you could embed the index logic into an `id` using `"#" + {{itemType}} + $index` as the selector on the list1 item.

Comment: Thanks for the details I will try it with ID as I have it already. Also please check updated part of my question.

Comment: When I use this code then it scrolls but not to that element exactly, also `[count[foodType]++]` I am not clear what it does. I am using `scrollTop: angular.element(foodType).offset().top` also after doing scroll I am not able to scroll upwards in the list it is blocked.

Comment: @A_user perhaps add an event listener for scroll to the list2 div reseting the `scrollTop` ... Also, add an offset by a few pixels so it lines up? I was thinking clicking multiple times would go to the next item based on iterating  `[count[foodType]++] ` if lets say i clicked on fruit more than once? Hope it helps.

Comment: How to set event listener on scroll and if I reset `scrollTop` then I think list will scroll to 0th element again.